# Automated build for developing ios and signing it

Tags: iphone, cordova, jenkins, build-automation

So I am building an phonegap application with android and ios platform to support. For android all is fine. I created an apk and signed it with google certificate.

Issue is with ios. 
Till now I was using an enterprise licence to distribute the app. All was working fine, since it allowed wildcard character in bundle name.

Now I need to move on with an developer licence. So everytime I create an app the bundle name will be different and so provisioning profile and keychain and certificate.

So is there a way, shell script only no manual step, to create an app id, create certificate, create keychain and sign the app with new keychain.

What exact steps are to create and sign an ios app.

I will be running a jenkins to build app.

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Ad Hoc Distribution** method. It is intended for testing purposes.You can create a wildcard App-ID for the Ad Hoc Distribution.

This method allows you to distribute apps to up to 100 iOS devices. You should register the test devices manually by their ID in the apple developer portal.

For more details:

[Developer.Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

[Create_an_ad-hoc_provisioning_profile](http://www.manyfriends.com/wiki/iphone/index.php/Create_an_ad-hoc_provisioning_profile)